# Why does `x[i]` return `x` when `i` is missing due to `recursive default argument reference`?

Tags: r, function, lazy-evaluation

The function below throws an error because of a recursive default argument reference. This is intended behavior because [default arguments are evaluated inside the scope of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8425348/16909768).

```r
i = 1
f1 = function(i=i) i
f1() # Error: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference
```

But if `i` is inside single brackets `[`, then there is no error, and the function returns `x` instead of the intended `x[i]`:

```r
x = 1:5
i = 1:3
f2 = function(x, i=i) x[i]
f2(x) # No error, but returns x, not x[i]
```

This is a silent error that leads to subtle bugs. For example, in machine learning we may think we are subsetting the training set (`x[i]`), but are actually using both the training and testing set (`x`). The behavior occurs even if the variable `i` doesn't exist:

```r
x = 1:5
if (exists("i")) rm(i)
f3 = function(x, i=i) x[i]
f3(x) # No error, but returns x, even if i doesnt exist.
```

A more reasonable behavior is when `i` is inside double brackets (`[[` instead of `[`), which throws a `missing subscript` error:

```r
x = 1:5
i = 1:3
f4 = function(x, i=i) x[[i]]
f4(x) # Error: missing subscript
```

My questions are:

- Is the behavior of `f2` and `f3` intended or is it a bug?
- If it is not a bug, then can someone explain the reasoning behind why it is intended? I briefly looked over the [R source code for subsetting](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/55cd975c538ad5a086c2085ccb6a3037d5a0cb9a/src/main/subset.c), but my knowledge of C is not enough to understand the behavior of `f2`.

Comment: Simply don't define a function with `i = foo` if `foo` isn't also an argument of the function and `foo` is to be evaluated. You can make `f2` safe by forcing evaluation: `f2 = function(x, i=i) {force(i); x[i]}`. The `[` .Primitive does some rather arcane stuff during evaluation.

Comment: Because a function's scope includes the parent environment, I strongly recommend against this kind of re-use of arg names.   It's as bad as  `foo <-function(x)  x + y `  which will happily execute if there's a `y` in the parent envir.

Comment: @Roland Another way to make `f2` safe is to specify in which frame to evaluate `i`: `f2 = function(x, i=parent.frame()$i) x[i]`. 


@CarlWitthoft I usually avoid reusing arg names (e.g. using `i=i_` in `f2`), but now it slipped through and I was surprised there was no error about a recursive default argument reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an edit to my original answer:

I think it's not a bug, though you can argue that it's a design flaw.

First,  there's an easy explanation for the difference between `x[i]` and `x[[i]]` behaviour:  `x[]` is legal, and returns `x`.  `x[[]]` is not legal, because it says to extract something, but doesn't say what.

Now, why did I say it is not a bug?  Take a look at this example, a little simpler than yours, and not using the primitive function `[`:

```r
f <- function(farg = farg) 
  if (missing(farg)) 
    message("Not an error:  farg is missing")

g <- function(garg)
  f(garg)

g()
#> Not an error:  farg is missing
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The function `f()` tests its argument using `missing(farg)`.  This doesn't ever evaluate the default value, it just reports on whether the argument was missing or not.  So `f()` never ends up trying to evaluate `farg`.

The function `[` is like `f`:  if the index is missing, it just returns the whole vector, it doesn't try to evaluate the index.  Since it never tries to evaluate `i`, it doesn't generate an error.

New addition:

But this explanation is incomplete.  @Roland suggested looking at code like this: (I've changed names to match my example more closely):

```r
g1 <- function(x, i=1) 
  x[i]
g1(1:5)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here `i` is missing in the call to `g1()`, but now it has a default value.  So when R tries to evaluate `x[i]` it will check whether `i` is missing.  It is evaluated in the context of `g1()`, where `missing(i)` would return true, but now we have a default value, so the missingness doesn't propagate, we get the default value 1 substituted for `i` and end up evaluating `x[1]`.

Now what if the default had been `i = i`, as in the original question?  Now when determining if `i` is missing in `x[i]`, R will substitute the default value and check that.  It finds that yes, `i` is missing, so `x[i]` returns the same thing as `x[]`.

So why is it a design flaw?  My first answer is that there's a question of whether missingness should propagate through function calls.  "Obviously" the argument is not missing in `f(garg)`, and yet R sees it as missing because `garg` was missing.  You would get the results you expected if missingness depended on the form of the call, not the value in it.  But that's not how R works.

My second answer is that it's a flaw because propagation of missingness is handled in a pretty subtle way.  Arguments with default values are replaced with their default before deciding what to propagate.

Comment: There is something missing from your answer. `f = function(x, i=1) missing(i); f(1:5)` returns `TRUE` but `f = function(x, i=1) x[i]; f(1:5)` returns `1`.

Comment: @Roland, an edit is in place now.  I still think it's not a bug, but it's more subtle than my original explanation.  Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: I was not totally "getting it" until you said *"if the index is missing"* (referencing `[`), at which point it all gelled in my head. Excellent walk-through, it definitely explains (in my mind) why OP's `f2` does not error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the main reasons for `f2`'s behavior are (i) how missingness is propagated with default args and (ii) the fact that `x[]` returns `x`. 

I would argue `f2` should communicate at least something to the user, even if it is not a bug. But if it could be fixed (without breaking compatibility), I assume it would have already been fixed, since`f2`'s behavior must have come up before somewhere in R's lifetime.

Comment: The behaviour of `x[]` makes a lot of sense in R.  Usually you see it with matrices, where `x[i, ]` gives row `i` and `x[, j]` gives row `j`, but it also applies to arrays with more indices, and vectors with just one.  I'm not so sure I like the propagation of missingness.